# How to fix SSRS does NOT count NULL as value?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm creating a report using SSRS, and I have a bunch of departments and I need to count the total of their running statuses. This is the result from my table

[image]
Please note, the UNKNOWN department shows NULL inside the table. i hard coded to 'UNKNOWN' --`ISNULL(department,'UNKNOWN')`
And i have tested the table has NULL record and I can count those NULL record `COUNT(*)`

However, it seems like SSRS does not count NULL values.
the SSRS expression i had its `=COUNT(Fields!ID.Value)`
I need UNKNOWN rows count just as other department

How do I fix this?

Comment: You should include your original SQL query.

Comment: I thought this has to deal with SSRS instead sql query

Comment: You can handle it in the SQL Query itself. Handle NULL Values as 0 in SQL Query so the Aggregation is not affected.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem comes from how the query was written. This is a guess (you didn't provide the query) but I expect you did something like this:

```
/* Start Demo Data */
DECLARE @Departments TABLE (DepartmentID INT IDENTITY, Name NVARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @Departments (Name) VALUES
('Architect'),('Business Intelligence Analyst'),('Data Analyst'),
('Database'),('Information Technology'),('Technical Analyst');

DECLARE @Tickets TABLE (TicketID INT IDENTITY, CreateDateUTC DATETIME DEFAULT GETUTCDATE(), DepartmentID INT, Status NVARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @Tickets (DepartmentID, Status) VALUES
(1, 'Completed'),
(2, 'Completed'),(2, 'Completed'),
(3, 'Completed'),(3, 'Completed'),(3, 'Completed'),(3, 'Completed'),(3, 'Completed'),
(3, 'Failure'),(3, 'Failure'),(3, 'Running'),(3, 'Running'),(3, 'Failure'),
(4, 'Completed'),
(5, 'Completed'),(5, 'Completed'),(5, 'Failure'),(5, 'Running'),(5, 'Completed'),
(6, 'Completed'),
(7, 'Failure'),(7, 'Completed');
/* End Demo Data */
```

```
SELECT COALESCE(d.Name,'Unknown') AS Department, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.Status = 'Completed' THEN 1 END) AS Completed,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.Status = 'Failure' THEN 1 END  ) AS Failure,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.Status = 'Running' THEN 1 END  ) AS Running,
       COUNT(t.Status) AS Total
  FROM @Departments d
    INNER JOIN @Tickets t
      ON t.DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID
 GROUP BY d.Name
 ORDER BY Department
```

```
Department                      Completed   Failure Running Total
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Architect                       1           0       0       1
Business Intelligence Analyst   2           0       0       2
Data Analyst                    5           3       2       10
Database                        1           0       0       1
Information Technology          3           1       1       5
Technical Analyst               1           0       0       1
```

This will find all the tickets with a matching department ID in the tickets table, but it will not return any tickets which have a non-matching value in the departmentID column, a NULL for example.

If you change your approach to something like:

```
SELECT COALESCE(d.Name,'Unknown') AS Department, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.Status = 'Completed' THEN 1 END) AS Completed,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.Status = 'Failure' THEN 1 END  ) AS Failure,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN t.Status = 'Running' THEN 1 END  ) AS Running,
       COUNT(t.Status) AS Total
  FROM @Tickets t
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @Departments d
      ON t.DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID
 GROUP BY d.Name
 ORDER BY Department
```

You're now asking for all the tickets, and joining that to the departments with a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` which allows non-matching rows from Tickets to be returned as well. When there is a non-matching (including NULL) value in the departmentID column, it's still part of the result set.

```
Department                      Completed   Failure Running Total
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Architect                       1           0       0       1
Business Intelligence Analyst   2           0       0       2
Data Analyst                    5           3       2       10
Database                        1           0       0       1
Information Technology          3           1       1       5
Technical Analyst               1           0       0       1
Unknown                         1           1       0       2
```

Comment: Thank you so much Patrick for this very details answer. But unfortunately its not about the JOIN. I can see those record exist in my table and i can count all department using COUNT(*)    So im pretty sure its something with SSRS expression, =COUNT(Fields!ID.Value)   Im not sure how can i edit this